# Python code for prime factoring creates a strange TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers

I'm writing a code for an assignment from school, the task is to prime factorize a number, and then  print out the numbers. For example: (**input: 20**) (**output: [2,2,5]**). It's a simple task, but it tends to have an error which I can't find out the solution after searching on the internet.
Here is the code:
(I use python 3.6.1 and write in IDLE)

```
answer = [ ]
while 1:
    try:
        num = input()
    except:
        break

    for i in range(2 , num+1):
        if (num%i) == 0:
            answer.append(i)
            num = num/i
        else:
            pass
        
    print (answer)
```

The error text is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Doc\Python\zerojudge\0625_a010.py", line 8, in <module>
    for i in range(2 , num+1):
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Please help, thank you very much.

Comment: `input` will take the number as str. Use `int(num) + 1`

Comment: In py3, `input()` returns all as `str`. Try `int(input())` to get the input as integer.

Comment: Ahh Totally forgot about that change in py3. Thanks!